# No Response when Restassured url has custom encoding

Tags: rest-assured

I am using rest-assured to test REST APIs, when hitting the url, url has it own encoded parameters.

```
 Response b = given().
                relaxedHTTPSValidation().body(gbody).
                with().
                contentType(ConfigReader.get("application.json")).
                then()
                .post(url);
```

It ran successfully but response is empty.

Please tell what can be the reason

Answer (score 0):

This is because, rest-assured will automatically encode the url when you are encoding the url, you need to use method `urlEncodingEnabled(false)`, so that , it will not encode the url again.

Now your code will become

```
Response res = given()
                .urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .body(gbody)
                .with()
                .contentType(ConfigReader.get("application.json"))
                .then()
                .post(url);
```